# Use modified property of object as parameter in Powershell for Set-MailPublicFolder

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, public-folders

When we create a public folder and mail enable in Exchange Online, the default email address is @domain.onmicrosoft.com

Our folder names are "NNNNN_Folder name" where NNNNN is a 5 digit number.

I would like to set the primary email address of the public folder to NNNNN@domain.com

I have tried many variations of this:

```
Get-PublicFolder -Recurse -Identity "\X\Y\Z"|
    Sort-Object Identity –Descending| 
    Select-Object -first 4|
    Set-MailPublicFolder  -PrimarySmtpAddress {$_.name.substring(0,5)+"@domain.com"}
```

and receive errors about interpreting the resulting email address:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'PrimarySmtpAddress'. Cannot convert value
"$_.name.substring(0,5)+"@domain.com"" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Data.SmtpAddress". Error: "The email
address "$_.name.substring(0,5)+"@domain.com"" isn't correct. Please use this format: user name, the @ sign,
followed by the domain name. For example, tonysmith@contoso.com or tony.smith@contoso.com."
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-MailPublicFolder], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Set-MailPublicFolder
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

I also tried setting the EmailAddress of the PublicFolder to NNNNN@domain.com in the same operation.

```
-EmailAddresses @{$_.name.substring(0,5)+"@domain.com"}
```

It doesn't seem to be evaluating the argument or I'm missing something else?

If I change `Set-MailPublicFolder ...` with
`% {$_.name.substring(0,5) + "@domain.com"}`

I do see the email addresses I am expecting.
Thanks,

Craig.

Comment: I removed my answer so it might attract others to answer it. That being said,  try replacing your Set-MailPublicFolder statement altogether by a Write-host with the full email address as it should appears. The null valued expression might have been because one of the name was empty.

Comment: @SagePourpre Thanks, I think you were on the right track.. it got me the closest of everything I tried.  I edited my OP to confirm that there are no empty names in the pipeline.  It has something to do with access to `$_` - this is what I can't figure out.  I read somewhere you need to use `{$_...}` to access.  But I tried that too.

Comment: See my new answer. It might be get your further. Hopefully, it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this version.

From Microsoft command documentation, the identity parameter is required (see [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123707(v=exchg.160).aspx))

I am also not sure it can take the array and process each individual without specifying a foreach.

See this modified versions.

```
$PublicFolders = Get-PublicFolder -Recurse -Identity "\X\Y\Z"| Sort-Object Identity –Descending | Select-Object -first 4

$PublicFolders | foreach {
                     $NewEmail = "$($_.name.substring(0,5))@domain.com"
                     Write-Host "Settings MailPublicFolder with name $($_.Identity) to $NewEmail" -ForegroundColor Cyan
                     Set-MailPublicFolder -Identity $_.Identity -PrimarySmtpAddress $NewEmail
                  }
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked.  I tried passing the identity into my earlier pipeline, it didn't help.